How to include the dependencies when running via java -jar command ? But it works fine in eclipse IDE?
I created 3 spring boot applications(ph-component, serviceA, serviceB) using eclipse IDE.
the ph-component has AOP related stuff, log4j2.xml file which acts as a common setting for other projects(serviceA, serviceB)
package com.bhn.core.phcomponent.aspect;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import brave.Span;
import brave.Tracer;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer;


@Aspect
@Component
public class TracingAspect {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TracingAspect.class);
    
    private final Timer spanTimer;
     
    private MeterRegistry meterRegistry;
    
    

    public TracingAspect(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        super();
        this.meterRegistry = meterRegistry;
        this.spanTimer = Timer.builder("span.duration")
                .description("Duration of a span")
                .register(meterRegistry);
    }

    @Pointcut(value= "execution(* com.bhn.core..*.*(..))")
    //@Pointcut(value= "execution(* *(..))") 
    private void logTraceAndSpanId()   
    {   
    }  
    
//  @Pointcut(value= "within(com.bhn.core.*)")  
//  private void logTraceAndSpanId()   
//  {   
//  }  
    
//    @Pointcut("execution(* brave.Span.start(..))")
//    private void spanStart() {}
//
//    @Pointcut("execution(* brave.Span.finish(..))")
//    private void spanFinish() {}
    
    
    @Around("logTraceAndSpanId()")
    public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object retValue = null;
        Timer.Sample sample = Timer.start();
        String methodName = proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        try {
            logger.info("starting " + methodName);
            retValue = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
            logger.info("ending " + methodName);  
            sample.stop(spanTimer);
            logger.info("Span duration: " + spanTimer.totalTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) + "ms");
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Exception occured when executing " + methodName + "\n" + ex.getMessage());
            throw ex;
        }
        return retValue;    
    }
}


log4j2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <!-- Configuration for JSON output when LOG_FORMAT is "json" -->
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="JsonConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <JsonLayout compact="true" eventEol="true">
                <KeyValuePair key="traceId" value="$${ctx:traceId}"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="spanId" value="$${ctx:spanId}"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="parentSpanId" value="$${ctx:parentSpanId}"/>
            </JsonLayout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <!-- Use JSON layout if LOG_FORMAT is "json", otherwise don't log -->
            <AppenderRef ref="JsonConsoleAppender" if="${env:LOG_FORMAT:equals(json)}"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

    <!-- Configuration for normal console printing when LOG_FORMAT is not "json" -->
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="NormalConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{75} - [Trace: %X{traceId}, Span: %X{spanId}, ParentSpanId: %X{parentSpanId}] %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <!-- Use pattern layout if LOG_FORMAT is not "json" -->
            <AppenderRef ref="NormalConsoleAppender" if="${env:LOG_FORMAT:notEquals(json)}"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>


project layout
Now i have added this project as a dependency in serviceA and service B pom.xml files :
serviceA/B pom.xml
now if i run the project in eclipse , by launching service A main class, im successfully able to see the following loggers(along with all the tracing aspects applied as part of ph-compnent dependency) :
2024-04-02 15:15:59 [main] INFO  com.bhn.core.phcomponent.aspect.TracingAspect - [Trace: , Span: , ParentSpanId: ] Span duration: 8.765935ms
2024-04-02 15:15:59 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.EndpointLinksResolver - [Trace: , Span: , ParentSpanId: ] Exposing 0 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2024-04-02 15:15:59 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - [Trace: , Span: , ParentSpanId: ] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8040"]
2024-04-02 15:15:59 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - [Trace: , Span: , ParentSpanId: ] Tomcat started on port 8040 (http) with context path ''
2024-04-02 15:15:59 [main] INFO  com.bhn.core.serviceA.ServiceAApplication - [Trace: , Span: , ParentSpanId: ] Started ServiceAApplication in 2.006 seconds (process running for 3.147)
2024-04-02 15:16:20 [http-nio-8040-exec-1] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - [Trace: , Span: , ParentSpanId: ] Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-04-02 15:16:20 [http-nio-8040-exec-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - [Trace: , Span: , ParentSpanId: ] Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-04-02 15:16:20 [http-nio-8040-exec-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - [Trace: , Span: , ParentSpanId: ] Completed initialization in 1 ms
2024-04-02 15:16:20 [http-nio-8040-exec-1] INFO  com.bhn.core.phcomponent.aspect.TracingAspect - [Trace: 660bd3ec3272a70a8ef23f0b5f5e0287, Span: 8ef23f0b5f5e0287, ParentSpanId: ] starting getMethodName
2024-04-02 15:16:20 [http-nio-8040-exec-1] INFO  com.bhn.core.phcomponent.HealthCheckPingController - [Trace: 660bd3ec3272a70a8ef23f0b5f5e0287, Span: 8ef23f0b5f5e0287, ParentSpanId: ] returning health metrics
2024-04-02 15:16:20 [http-nio-8040-exec-1] INFO  com.bhn.core.phcomponent.aspect.TracingAspect - [Trace: 660bd3ec3272a70a8ef23f0b5f5e0287, Span: 8ef23f0b5f5e0287, ParentSpanId: ] ending getMethodName
2024-04-02 15:16:20 [http-nio-8040-exec-1] INFO  com.bhn.core.phcomponent.aspect.TracingAspect - [Trace: 660bd3ec3272a70a8ef23f0b5f5e0287, Span: 8ef23f0b5f5e0287, ParentSpanId: ] Span duration: 13.782512ms
2024-04-02 15:16:36 [http-nio-8040-exec-2] INFO  com.bhn.core.phcomponent.aspect.TracingAspect - [Trace: 660bd3fcdbc36a85229d91e6f167cea1, Span: 229d91e6f167cea1, ParentSpanId: ] starting getTestResponse
2024-04-02 15:16:36 [http-nio-8040-exec-2] INFO  com.bhn.core.serviceA.controller.HomeController - [Trace: 660bd3fcdbc36a85229d91e6f167cea1, Span: 229d91e6f167cea1, ParentSpanId: ] returning welcome message
2024-04-02 15:16:36 [http-nio-8040-exec-2] INFO  com.bhn.core.phcomponent.aspect.TracingAspect - [Trace: 660bd3fcdbc36a85229d91e6f167cea1, Span: 229d91e6f167cea1, ParentSpanId: ] ending getTestResponse
2024-04-02 15:16:36 [http-nio-8040-exec-2] INFO  com.bhn.core.phcomponent.aspect.TracingAspect - [Trace: 660bd3fcdbc36a85229d91e6f167cea1, Span: 229d91e6f167cea1, ParentSpanId: ] Span duration: 14.298045ms

But if i run in command line using "java -jar serviceA-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar", then the ph-component dependency log4j2.xml settings/aspect code are not at all included . the output is like this :
2024-04-02T13:34:31.262+05:30  INFO 20540 --- [serviceA] [           main] [                                                 ] c.b.c.s.ServiceAApplication              : Starting ServiceAApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 21.0.2 with PID 20540 (/Users/rkuma04/Downloads/pHub/serviceA/target/serviceA-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by rkuma04 in /Users/rkuma04/Downloads/pHub/serviceA/target)
2024-04-02T13:34:31.275+05:30  INFO 20540 --- [serviceA] [           main] [                                                 ] c.b.c.s.ServiceAApplication              : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-04-02T13:34:32.611+05:30  INFO 20540 --- [serviceA] [           main] [                                                 ] o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer              : Tomcat initialized with port 8040 (http)
2024-04-02T13:34:32.626+05:30  INFO 20540 --- [serviceA] [           main] [                                                 ] o.a.c.c.StandardService                  : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-04-02T13:34:32.626+05:30  INFO 20540 --- [serviceA] [           main] [                                                 ] o.a.c.c.StandardEngine                   : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.19]
2024-04-02T13:34:32.661+05:30  INFO 20540 --- [serviceA] [           main] [                                                 ] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]                        : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-04-02T13:34:32.663+05:30  INFO 20540 --- [serviceA] [           main] [                                                 ] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1311 ms
2024-04-02T13:34:33.413+05:30  INFO 20540 --- [serviceA] [           main] [                                                 ] o.s.b.a.e.w.EndpointLinksResolver        : Exposing 0 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2024-04-02T13:34:33.489+05:30  INFO 20540 --- [serviceA] [           main] [                                                 ] o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer              : Tomcat started on port 8040 (http) with context path ''
2024-04-02T13:34:33.503+05:30  INFO 20540 --- [serviceA] [           main] [                                                 ] c.b.c.s.ServiceAApplication              : Started ServiceAApplication in 2.698 seconds (process running for 6.187)


Now i need ur people help, to fix this.
Due to this, im unable to see the same output if i run inside the docker container, with the command ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"].
sample docker file :
FROM amazoncorretto:21.0.2-al2-generic

WORKDIR /app

COPY target/*.jar /app/app.jar
ENV LOG_FORMAT=json
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
#ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Ddebug", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]

the serviceA-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar if i do a jar -xf serviceA-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar, it has ph-component.jar file inside boot-inf/lib. folder :
created: META-INF/
 inflated: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  created: META-INF/services/
 inflated: META-INF/services/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider
  created: org/
.....
extracted: BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar
extracted: BOOT-INF/lib/micrometer-observation-1.12.3.jar
extracted: BOOT-INF/lib/micrometer-commons-1.12.3.jar
extracted: BOOT-INF/lib/micrometer-jakarta9-1.12.3.jar
extracted: BOOT-INF/lib/ph-component-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
extracted: BOOT-INF/lib/aspectjweaver-1.9.21.jar
extracted: BOOT-INF/lib/micrometer-core-1.12.3.jar
....

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.
